# ComboBox not showing text after binding

Tags: c#

I just bound my combobox to database but it is not showing me values. However, I can see by the length of dropdown box that values are in it but aren't visible.

I just clicked on a value and it did work and took me to the next form. But how can I make those values visible?

```
  private void StudentLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select Std_ID  from Student", con);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Std_ID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        metroComboBox1.ValueMember = "Std_ID";
        metroComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        metroComboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
     private void metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs    e)
    {
        string ID = metroComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried calling the `.DataBind()` method? what type of application is this? and why are you using DataReader to populate the DataTable? why not Adapter?

Comment: I think the problem is in your query: cmd = new SqlCommand("select Std_ID  from Student", con); does not contain the name. Instead try the following: cmd = new SqlCommand("select Std_ID, Name  from Student", con);

Comment: This is a windows forms applciation. if i have to use databind then i could have just connected that combobox to database directly by using it properties but i decided to write code and do this by reading data from database using Select query.

Comment: Hey @Tyron78 yes you are right the problem is in the query and now it is showing me names of students but i want it to show me ID of students. What should i do for that?

Comment: In this case the DisplayMember should be Std_ID as well

Comment: Thanks @Tyron78. Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: OK. I posted it as answer as well - would be great if you could accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your query:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select Std_ID from Student", con);
```

does not contain the name. Instead try the following:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select Std_ID, Name from Student", con);
```

In order to display the ID instead of the name, put Std_ID as displaymamber as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
metroComboBox1.DataSource = dt;
metroComboBox1.ValueMember = "Std_ID";
metroComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
metroComboBox1.DataBind();
```